# How to pass a strongly typed MarshalByRefObject across an AppDomain boundary?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a scenario where I'd like to achieve simple communication between a parent `AppDomain` and its children. What I'm trying to do looks like it's going to work but I have come upon a snag, the below snippet is an example.

The program results in the message *No constructor found for C::.ctor(System.MarshalByRefObject)* so it looks like the runtime has rejected the constructor taking a parameter of the type that I'm passing in to the `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` call. I can understand why instantiating `B` works and I expected `C` to behave the same, so why does it not?

Thanks!

EDIT: I have made a small update to the sample code below after Hans pointed out a pedestrian mistake in my first example. So while we still have a fictional `ApplicationBase` property on our child application domains we can see that the correct assembly is loaded and the constructor we're trying to invoke can be seen.

Hans' observation **does** make the code work but I don't think I can set the ApplicationBase in the real thing to be the parent domain's base.

The output for the second iteration of the loop is now as follows:
*C

Initially Loaded: mscorlib

After Unwrap: mscorlib

After Unwrap: Foo

Void .ctor(A)

Constructor on type 'C' not found.*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class A : MarshalByRefObject { }

class B : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public B(MarshalByRefObject obj) { }
}

class C : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public C(A obj) { }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        foreach (var type in new [] { typeof(B), typeof(C) })
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);

                var setup = CreateSetup();

                var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("foo", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup);

                foreach (var ass in domain.GetAssemblies())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Initially Loaded: {0}", ass.GetName().Name);
                }

                domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(typeof(A).Assembly.Location, typeof(A).FullName);

                foreach (var ass in domain.GetAssemblies())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("After Unwrap: {0}", ass.GetName().Name);
                }

                var constructors = domain.GetAssemblies()
                    .ToList()
                    .SelectMany(ass => ass.DefinedTypes)
                    .First(t => t.Name == "C")
                    .GetConstructors();

                foreach (var constructor in constructors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(constructor);
                }

                CreateWrapped(domain, type);

                AppDomain.Unload(domain);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    static AppDomainSetup CreateSetup()
    {
        return new AppDomainSetup
        {
            ApplicationBase = "foo",
            ApplicationName = "bar",
            DisallowBindingRedirects = false,
            ConfigurationFile = "baz",
            LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost
        };
    }

    static object CreateWrapped(AppDomain domain, Type type)
    {
        return domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
            assemblyFile: type.Assembly.Location,
            typeName: type.FullName,
            ignoreCase: false,
            bindingAttr: BindingFlags.Default,
            binder: null,
            args: new object[] { new A() },
            culture: null,
            activationAttributes: null
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: AppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase is the problem.  Resolving the A type is a chicken-and-egg problem, it can't find the assembly that contains A.

Comment: Oh my god, how did I miss that when writing this. My real problem mustn't be captured by this Minimum non-Working Example.

Comment: @HansPassant, I've updated the sample, would you mind taking another look?

Comment: You did not solve the core problem but are getting closer.  Save the return value from the CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap() call for the A object and pass *that* one as the constructor argument.

Comment: The reason I've performed the Create..Unwrap for an object of type A is just to ensure that the assembly containing C is loaded in the child domain as I wanted to verify constructor visibility afterwards. Objects of type A will eventually be the communication media so I have to create them in the parent domain. Thanks for your assistance though Hans, I definitely feel like I'm getting closer to understanding the problem.

Comment: @arfbtwn Did you ever get to a final solution/conclusion?  Please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans pointed out the problem was the `ApplicationBase` in my `CreateSetup` function which I've corrected here:

```
static AppDomainSetup CreateSetup()
{
    return new AppDomainSetup
    {
        ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        ApplicationName = "bar",
        DisallowBindingRedirects = false,
        ConfigurationFile = "baz",
        LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost
    };
}
```

With this modification the example program executes correctly with both `B` and `C` instantiated in their child domains.

The forced assembly loading that I was performing isn't necessary after this change though I still can't explain why the child application domain is unable to resolve the `C` constructor after first constructing an `A` object to load the required assembly.

My best attempt at an explanation is that using the default [load context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782(v=vs.110).aspx#load_contexts) with an application domain having an invalid path specified for its base causes the resolution failure at probing time for `C`.